# Why am I missing a section?

Tags: html, css

So here's what I should be getting

[image]

But this is what I'm getting

[image]

As you can see the yellow section is missing. Here's my working example http://jsfiddle.net/Qk543/ but for some weird reason I cannot replicate it. Here's my code for the defective page.

```
        <div class="wrap">
           <div class="foot">
  <ul class="styl">
    <a id="html" href="#">
      <li style="background: #F16529">
        WORD
      </li>
    </a>
    <a id="css" href="#">
      <li style="background: #2AA9E0">
        WORD
      </li>
    </a>
    <a id="php" href="#">
      <li style="background: #8892BF">
        WORD
      </li>
    </a>
    <a id="js" href="#">
      <li style="background: #F0DB4F">
        WORD
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>

        </div>
```

And the CSS to it...

```
h1 {
    padding: 80px 0 40px;

    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: #505762;
}
    .search h1 {
        padding: 60px 0;
    }

.slidey {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0;

    background: #f3f5f8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e8ed;
}
    .js-enabled .slidey {
        -webkit-transition: margin-top .2s;
        -moz-transition: margin-top .2s;
        transition: margin-top .2s;
    }
    .slidey b, .slidey label {
        display: block;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding-bottom: 15px;

        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .slidey form, .slidey aside {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
        .slidey form input {
            padding: 20px;
            width: 75%;
        }
    .slidey li {
        list-style: none;
    }
        .slidey a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;

            color: #717985;
        }
            .slidey a:hover {
                color: #414b59;
            }
        .slidey li span {
            float: right;
            opacity: .6;
        }

#top {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 35px;

    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.1);
}
    #top a {
        float: left;

        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: none;

        color: #8895a7;
    }
        #top #logo:hover, #top ul a:hover, #top ul .active a, .posts .items li:first-child h2 a:hover, p a:hover {
            color: #4171b1;
        }
    #top ul {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
    }
        #top ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-left: 40px;
        }
        #top ul a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #555f6d;
        }
        #top ul img {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;

            position: relative;
            top: -2px;

            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;

            opacity: .4;
        }
            #top ul a:hover img {
                opacity: .7;
            }
            #top ul a.active img {
                opacity: 1;
            }

/**
 *   Index page listing, category listing, search page results
 */
.items {
    list-style: none;
}
    .items > li {
        padding: 70px 0 60px;

        color: #97aec9;
        background: #3c4552;
    }
        .posts .items > li:first-child {
            background: #fff !important;
            padding: 110px 0;
        }
            .items li h1 a, .posts .items > li:first-child h2 a {
                color: #3d4551;
            }
    .items h1 {
        padding: 0 0 8px;
    }
        .items h1 a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    .items h2 {
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 41px;
    }
        .items h2 a {
            display: block;
            padding-bottom: 12px;

            color: #fff;
            color: rgba(176,200,236,.8);

            text-decoration: none;
        }
            .items h2 a:hover {
                color: #fff;
            }
    .items .content {
        padding: 10px 0 0;
    }
        .items .content p {
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

/**
 *   Pagination
 */
.pagination {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    border-top: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.1);
}
    .pagination:empty {
        display: none;
    }
    .pagination a {
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;

        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;

        color: #6f7b8b;
    }
        .pagination a:hover {
            color: #3c4857;
        }
    .pagination a.next {
        float: right;
    }

/**
 *   Give some extra space to single-page wrappers
 */
.content.wrap {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
    .content.wrap ul, .content.wrap ol, .items li ul {
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }
        .content.wrap ul ul, .content.wrap ol ol, .items li ul ul {
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

/**
 *   Footnotes and straplines
 */
.footnote, .commentlist time, .items footer {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 15px;

    color: #98a2b1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;

    white-space: nowrap;
}
    .footnote {
        padding: 20px 0 40px;
    }

/**
 *   Comment form
 */
ul.commentlist {
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.1);
}
    ul.commentlist .wrap {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.commentlist li {
        padding: 40px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.1);
    }
        ul.commentlist time {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        ul.commentlist h2 {
            font-size: 25px;
            line-height: 33px;
        }
        ul.commentlist .counter {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;

            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #cdd2da;
        }

#comment {
    overflow: hidden;
}
    #comment label[for] {
        display: none;
    }
    #comment p {
        float: left;
        width: 48%;
        margin-right: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        text-indent: 0;
    }
        #comment p + p {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        #comment p.textarea {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
        }
    #comment input, #comment textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 15px;

        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: normal;

        border: 1px solid rgba(22,36,54,.2);
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
        #comment input:focus, #comment textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
            background: #f7f9fc;
        }
        #comment textarea {
            min-height: 150px;
            max-height: 800px;
            resize: vertical;
        }
    #comment button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 9px 18px;

        background: #4e82ce;
        color: #fff;

        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;

        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
        #comment button:hover {
            background: #3c6eb7;
        }

*{padding:0;margin:0;} 
body {
text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.foot{
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
width:100%; 
margin: 0px;
font-weight: 400;
}


.foot li{ 
opacity: 0.95;
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
width: 25%;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
}
.foot a{
font-size: 1.5em;
color: #fff;
height: 75px;
position: relative;
text-indent: 0;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 60px;

}
.foot li:nth-child(1){
background: #B36C4E;
}

.foot li:nth-child(2){
background: #2AA9E0;
}
.foot li:nth-child(3){
background: #8892BF;
}

.foot li:nth-child(4){
background: #F0DB4F;
}
a:link{text-decoration: none}
a:hover{text-decoration: none}
a:visited{text-decoration: none}
a:active{text-decoration: none}
.content {
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;

}



    Any ideas?
```

Comment: If you can't replicate the issue, we can't either. Keep debugging.

Comment: Uh...if the code you provide does not replicate the problem you describe, it's going to be tough to help. Do you have an example of the problem actually happening?

Comment: A `ul` should only have `li`s as direct children. You technically have  invalid markup, and there's no guarantee that your browser can render it correctly, although most browsers try their best. Put your `a` elements inside your `li`s and see what happens.

Comment: @Anonymous "Here's my working example http://jsfiddle.net/Qk543/ but for some weird reason I cannot replicate it"

Comment: Yeah, always start here when debugging HTML related issues: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @735Tesla Whoops, I guess I missed that.

Comment: That's what I did, but then the full section won't be an anchor @ajp15243

Comment: @user3444414 You can make your `a` elements fill the entire `li` box in a variety of ways, thereby effectively turning the `li`s themselves into links like you want, while still keeping valid markup.

Comment: Not ever sure what was wrong. I just merged them together and it works fine. Thanks for the validation tip and help. @ajp15243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using floats, so there's a good chance your last element is a pixel or so too wide for the container it's in and it's floating to the next line.

Try changing the width to 24% on each element and you'll probably see all four.

If you don't want to play with the width, try adding this to your css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

That includes any padding/margin in the width so that 25% width will be the true width instead of 25% plus padding/margin.